# How do I link two mirrored sides?

Tags: rendering, modifiers, mirror

So I've created an X and I used a mirror to make the right side of the X and have it symmetrical to the left side. As shown in the picture: [image: The X]

The problem I am having is when the image is rendered it looks like this:
[image: Rendered X]

At the axis of symmetry for the X there is a weird black line? I think it's due to two lines meeting at the same points? I don't know how to fix this and I would really appreciate any help. This is my first time using blender ._.

Comment: Have you checked the merge option in the modifier panel ?

Comment: @Aleph Yes that option is checked. http://i.imgur.com/B8D8ZHG.png

Comment: And why not applying the modifier and 'w'-> 'removed all doubles'? Unless you want to have the possibility of a further modification...

Comment: @Aleph What does "remove all doubles" do?

Comment: It merge the overlapping vertices, try my answer above, I've added some precisions :)

Comment: I think it's not necessary to apply mirror modifier in order to get rid of artifacts. First check whether these vertices (located on the mirror plane) are co-planar or select them and scale by Y axis to `0`. Second, check whether there are internal faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this can be many things:

- First try to change the `merge limit` value, and have a render.

If it doesn't work :

- in Edit mode, while zooming at maximum, make the twins vertices (of the top of your object, for example) -one for each side or your mirrored object - the closest as possible, overlapping themselves. 
  Try a Render, it should solve the pb.

If not :

- if you don't plan to have further modification on your shape, once it's finished, in Edit mode, you can apply the mirror modifier, then press `A` (it will select all the vertices), then `W`, then `remove doubles`, it will merge the overlapped vertices
  And try a render :)

Comment: thanks for the assistance  :D this worked perfectly, I changed the merge limit until the vertices merged. (and remove doubles sounds like it will be useful in the future :P )